# What could be the xpath/Css selector for below HTML tag, How to select a specific radio button using Selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, radio-button, webdriverwait

1. What could be the xpath/Css selector for below HTML tag , My question is How to click on a radio button of **Bike**.
2. let's Assume below are the dynamic radio button, we have 100 numbers radio buttons are present and here we can not predict the index number of our radio button

HTML:

```
<table> 
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="textAlignCenter" id="clientDocTypeSelection"><input class="marginL10" name="clientRadio" type="radio"></td><td id="clientDocTypeDescription"> Bike </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="textAlignCenter" id="clientDocTypeSelection"><input class="marginL10" name="clientRadio" type="radio"></td><td id="clientDocTypeDescription"> Car </td></tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To `click()` on the [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) with text as **Bike** you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='clientDocTypeDescription' and normalize-space()='Bike']//preceding::td[1]/input")).click();
  ```
- Using *Java* and `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'Bike')]//preceding::td[1]/input")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@id='clientDocTypeDescription' and normalize-space()='Bike']//preceding::td[1]/input"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Java* and `contains()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'Bike')]//preceding::td[1]/input"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but in my requirement I really I don't know td index number of Bike then how i will select the radio button

Comment: @SoumyaRanjanDas The required `<input>` would be always at index 1. Even removing the index should work seamless.

Comment: Thank you so much , you are really helpful ... Appreciating you .. thanks a lot, it's working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Find the `td` with the text you are looking for like this:

```
tds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='textAlignCenter']")
for td in tds:
   if td.text == 'Bike':
      radio_input = td.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio']")
```

Comment: look for solution in java

Comment: I don't think it will take you a lot of effort to translate the code in Java